# SPSS version 22 ERROR: attempt to connect to a remote server failed

Tags: windows-7, installation, spss

I have installed SPSS statistics 22 on my Win7 Home 64-bit SP 1 and it will not run. I am on an HP Pavilion dv7 with tons of RAM and disk.

Authorized copy (not network) standalone install with the 20-character authentication key.

I've been with IBM's ECuRep support for SPSS and still the software will not run (not that they were really any help). I'm working on this problem for 3 weeks now.

The error on startup:

```
Attempt to connect to a remote server failed inet:Local Computer: 0
```

I have purchased the software twice from two separate vendors, neither have been any help. Looking for ANY advice that may help. This is the student Version 22 standard Grad Pack.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of that might cause this is a misconfigured firewall.  Although Statistics would be running entirely on the one machine, it may use communications between the frontend and backend processes that are being intercepted and blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and called IBM support. They said it could be because SPSS was not installed with admin rights, recommended to remove and delete files under program files then reinstall. That did not help.

Then a friend told me he had a similar problem but the 32 bit version worked for him, so I tried. It worked once then it died again.

Finally, I installed version 21 64 bit. That worked.